# fgetc read only 39 bytes from file

Tags: c, gcc

This programm reads only 39 bytes. After this everything reads as '-1'

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    FILE *file =fopen("Eva.wav","r");
    if (file==NULL)
        printf("heresy read!");
    
    for(int i=0;i<200;i++)
    {
        char a = fgetc(file);
        printf("%hhX ",a);
    }
    fclose(file);
    return 0;
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MeOx4.png)

I rewrite code using fread function. After 39 byte comes something absolute other byte code. Looks like segmented file. But if it so, why fread and fgets result are different?

```
C:\Users\phoenix\Documents\gccex\serial>a.exe
52 49 46 46 46 FF8C FFA3 0 57 41 56 45 66 6D 74 20 10 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 44 FFAC 0 0 44 FFAC 0 0 1 0 8 0 4C 49 53 54 FF86 FFAA 6A FFFB FFFE 7F 0 0 FF88 2C 40 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 10 15 40 0 0 0 0 0 8 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 11 0 1 10 0 0 0 0 60 7 FF96 0 0 0 0 0 FF86 FFAA 6A FFFB FFFE 7F 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 FFB0 16 40 0 0 0 0 0 10 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 50 13 FF96 0 0 0 0 0 FF83 16 40 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 6 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 70 13 FF96 0 0 0 0 0 FFB0 16 40 0 0 0 0 0 FFFF FFFF FFFF FFFF FFFF FFFF FFFF FFFF FF99 17 40 0 0 0 0 0 10 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 FF99 16 40 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 6 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

What is the right way to read file?

Comment: The returned value `-1` is the `EOF` flag. *Why fread and fgets result are different?* `fread` is for binary files, `fgets` is for text files. You should not open a `.wav` as a text file.

Comment: Where did you read `char a = fgetc(file);`? The function docs tell you it returns `int`. The `char` is never (?) used in C libraries as a function argument, or as a function return value. They use `int` and note that `'A'` is not `char` type, it is `int`. Beginner's error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On Microsoft Windows, binary files should be opened in binary mode (`"rb"`), not text mode (`"r"`). A WAVE file is a binary file.

> After this everything reads as '-1'

This statement is incorrect. You are no longer reading anything. The function `fgetc` is returning the macro constant `EOF`, which is defined as `-1` on most platforms. This should become apparant if you check for `EOF`, by changing your loop to the following:

```
    for(int i=0;i<200;i++)
    {
        int a = fgetc(file); //the type must be int, not char

        if ( a == EOF )
        {
            printf( "EOF\n" );
            break;
        }

        printf("%hhX ",a);
    }
```

When `fgetc` returns `EOF`, this means that either end-of-file has been reached or an error has occurred. In this case, it is due to end-of-file.

On Microsoft Windows, when a file is opened in text mode, the character code `0x1A` is interpreted as the end of the file. According to your posted screenshot, your file happens to have the value `0x1A` at file offset `0x28`. That is the reason why you can only read up to file offset `0x27` (`39` in decimal) in the file. To fix this, open the file in binary mode instead of text mode.

Comment: "On Microsoft Windows" is incorrect.  It is not an OS issue, but a compiler issue.  E.g. GCC on Windows does not have this issue.

Comment: @chux: Are you saying that the MinGW version of gcc does not distinguish between text mode and binary mode, i.e. that it has POSIX behavior?

Comment: At least in my case using _x86_64-pc-cygwin_ gcc on Windows, text streams act like binary ones.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica That's because you're using the **cygwin** gcc, which emulates POSIX behavior. The **mingw** gcc also distinguishes between text mode and binary mode.

Answer (score 2):

"What is the right way to read file?"

Annotated example below:

```
// #include <windows.h> // Not needed for this program
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char *fname = "Eva.wav"; // re-usable string

    FILE *file = fopen( fname, "rb" ); // NB: "binary mode" for Windows
    if( file == NULL ) {
        fprintf( stderr, "Cannot open '%s'\n", fname ); // See?
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE ); // do not continue
    }
    
    unsigned char buf[ 200 ]; // OP wants to 'sniff' first 200 bytes

    // "correct" way to read bytes
    // Could use loop, reading 1, 20, or 50 bytes at a time. Why?
    size_t nRead = fread( buf, sizeof buf[0], sizeof buf, file );

    fclose( file ); // close when no longer needed

    // only bytes loaded, not quantity expected
    for( size_t i = 0; i < nRead; i++ )
        printf( "%02X ", buf [ i ] ); // "old school". may be antiquated

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Thank you... Obvious when you point it out to the fool! `:-)`